# Running Models in Sirius

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-sirius

with the Eclipse plugin Sirius you can develop a user interface for creating models given the rules of your EMF meta-model much easier than getting your hands dirty directly with GMF. This is really cool!

However, **how can you run the models in the user interface?** Can you please give me some pointers?

For the purpose of the explanation, let's say that you create in Sirius the user interface for creating statecharts, but how can you run them? Throw Event 1, running State 1 is stopped and State2 starts... (you know what I mean).

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches to do that, one of the most promising one is using a "lab" component https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/lab.html and is called "Sirius Animator".

It is currently compatible with Sirius 2.0 and would probably need to be upgrade for the version you are targeting.

Comment: Thanks! Im installing GEMOC Studio to check it right away..looks promising.

Comment: Hi @CedricBrun , GEMOC is really cool. I get though an Xtend Error. Can you please help me? I have Xtend and AspectJ installed so I do not know why is this an error. The compiler is saying that there are multiple markers in line 111 of /org.gemoc.arduino.concurrent.k3dsa/src/org/gemoc/arduino/concurrent/k3dsa/OperationalSemantics.xtend, namely, here: @Aspect(className=Instruction).